# difference between numpy randint and floor of rand

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, scientific-computing

```
num_draws = int(1e6)
arr1 = np.random.randint(0, 10, num_draws)
arr2 = np.floor(10*np.random.rand(num_draws))
```

Could someone with expertise in the internals of numpy.random comment on whether arr2 obeys formally equivalent statistics to arr1? In experiments I have done, the distributions appear to have the same first few moments, but that's all I have checked thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, they're equivalent** `[1]`

Looking at the source code, they both are defined in auxiliary functions ([1](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1181),[2](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L1577)) that reference underlying C calls based on the data size ([1](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L318), [2](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L514))- these both make a call to [the same underlying function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/random/mtrand/randomkit.c#L221).

That underlying function is a 32-bit [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister). Everything on top of this call is shifts and masking to coerce the right data type, but it doesn't change the underlying behaviour of the randomness.

---

**Footnotes**

`[1]` I assume you're not asking whether your method of flooring the number has unexpected statistical side-effects. That doesn't depend on numpy, but since they both use the same uniform statistical device, they should have the same bias. I would not expect them to have the same performance

Comment: thanks for clarifying. The ~10% performance hit of using rand instead of randint is ok by me - there are certain situations where `arr2` fits much more naturally into the problem than `arr1`.